# Non-blocking Data Structure, Multiple Readers, Single Writer

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, nonblocking

I've a very specific scenario:

1. Several (manycore not multicore) TPL Tasks (long-running so likely to be threads) want to read a collection of data (e.g. a IDictionary) in a parallel/overlapping manner
2. One Writer thread wants to periodically update the entire collection
3. Minimizing latency for the readers is #1 goal, even if that means picking up a slightly stale collection (i.e. a collection update is in-progress)
4. The readers **must** get the collection in its entirety, a partially updated collection is not valid

Initially the thinking was to avoid (4) that a new collection is created each time an update occurs and once created the writer thread could simply change the collection reference given to the readers. The implicit assumption being that this would be an atomic operation, readers with the old reference would be unaffected and new readers could access the new complete collection.

I get a partially updated collection when I try it, so I need to know if this approach *can* work before proceeding further...

Comment: Did you try System.Collections.Concurrent things? such as ConcurrentDictionary, ConcurrentBag, .....

Comment: Of course :) from my scan of the MSDN docs, they _appear_ to employ blocking/locking for reads and/or writes. Here we hope to avoid that (low-latency == #1 goal) by performing a flick-of-a-switch so that no locking is required. Is this possible?

Comment: @StephenS, switching a refrence is an atomic operation, its just an int32 pointer, right? So your idea seems logical to me.

Comment: Exactly my think thinking. So perhaps it's my implementation that's flawed. Thanks for the replies guys...

Comment: Yep - flawed implementation. I was doing reference copies of the existing Dictionary contents. Zips along nicely with sub-millisecond average accesses times for all Tasks/Threads. Thanks again.

Comment: @StephenS Then you should post that as an answer and accept it, when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a while since posting but IIRC I was creating a new collection using the old collection as a constructor parameter - i.e. a shallow copy.

Doing a proper copy of the elements and instantiating the new container with those gave me the decoupling of data items I needed to ensure no 'tearing'.